# Adding new users by pushing element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my static info:

```
$scope.users = {
    "Eriks": {
        "name": "Kreg",
        "surname": "Indo",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "age" : "2",
        "tel" : "+123123 22"
    }
};
```

I am adding a new user:

```
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.users.push({name:$scope.newUser.name, surname:$scope.newUser.surname, email:$scope.newUser.email, age:$scope.newUser.age, tel:$scope.newUser.tel});
    $scope.newUser = "";
};
```

It works when I have different type of `$scope.users` like this

```
$scope.users = [{"name":"Kreg"}...more...];
```

and here is my form

```
<small>Name: </small> <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.name"><br/>
<small>Surname: </small> <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.surname"><br/>
<small>E-mail: </small> <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.email"><br/>
<small>Age: </small> <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.age"><br/>
<small>Telephone: </small> <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.tel"><br/>
<button ng-click="add()">add new user</button>
```

So what should I change in my `add()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push to an object like `{}`. Just set the key instead, like `$scope.users[key] = userData;`

Your second example works because it's a proper `array` that supports `push`.